# FCKEditor doesn't set Value property on postback!

Tags: asp.net, postback, fckeditor

I'm using [FCKEditor](http://www.fckeditor.net) on my asp.net web page.  It appears beautifully, and the editor looks really good on the front end.  Only problem is, the .Value property is not being set on the postback.  No matter what changes the user makes to the value of the control on the page, when I click "Submit", the .Value property remains blank.

I have Googled for other solutions, and most of them are of the variety where there's some conflict with Ajax, such as [this](http://www.daveparslow.com/2007/10/fckeditor-inside-updatepanel-broken.html) and [this](http://blogs.uct.ac.za/blog/lovemores-world/2008/10/27/post-fckeditor-form-with-ajax-solved).  My problem is not solved by these solutions; it's much more fundamental than that.  I'm not doing anything to do with Ajax; I'm just a simple asp.net newbie with a simple web form, and the value property is not being set on postback, not in IE and not in FF.

It appears that at least [one other person](http://www.fckeditor.net/forums/viewtopic.php?f=5&t=12995&start=0) has had this problem, but no solution yet.

Any ideas?
Thanks!

---

New information:
I tried this out on a "hello world" test web site - and the test web site works 100%.  There is obviously a problem on my page, but I have no idea where to begin tracking this down.

Here's the markup of my page, in case anyone can see anything obvious that my newbie eyes can't:

```
<%@ Page Language="vb" AutoEventWireup="false" CodeBehind="EmailTemplateEditForm.aspx.vb"
  Inherits="EEI_App.EmailTemplateEditForm" %>

<%@ Register Assembly="FredCK.FCKeditorV2" Namespace="FredCK.FCKeditorV2" TagPrefix="FCKeditorV2" %>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
  <title>EEI - Email Template</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="EEI.css">

  <script language="javascript" id="jssembleWare" src="sembleWare.js"></script>

  <style type="text/css">
    .style1
    {
      height: 251px;
    }
    .style2
    {
      width: 2%;
      height: 251px;
    }
    .style3
    {
      height: 490px;
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <form id="form1" runat="server">
  <%@ register src="header.ascx" tagname="header" tagprefix="uc1" %>
  <%@ register src="footer.ascx" tagname="footer" tagprefix="uc1" %>
  <uc1:header ID="header1" runat="server" />
  <!-- main content area -->
  <div class="content">
    <!-- title of the page -->
    <div class="boxheader">
      Email Template
    </div>
    <div class="standardbox">
      <!-- Start Page Main Contents-->
      <!-- error messages -->
      <div class="errorbox">
        <asp:Label ID="lblError" CssClass="ErrorControlStyle" runat="server" EnableViewState="False"
          Width="100%"></asp:Label>
      </div>
      <table class="contenttable">
        <tr>
          <td align="left" valign="top" class="style3">
            <div class="actionbox">
              <div class="navheadertitle">
                Navigation</div>
              <ul>
                <li>
                  <asp:LinkButton ID="btnSubmit" CssClass="LinkButtonStyle" runat="server">Submit</asp:LinkButton>
                </li>
                <li>
                  <asp:LinkButton ID="btnCancel" CssClass="LinkButtonStyle" runat="server" CausesValidation="false">Cancel</asp:LinkButton>
                </li>
              </ul>
            </div>
          </td>
          <td align="left" valign="top" class="style3">
            <p>
            </p>
            <table>
              <tr class="MCRSFieldRow">
                <td class="MCRSFieldLabelCell">
                  <asp:Label ID="lblEmailTemplate_TemplateName" CssClass="LabelStyle" runat="server"
                    Width="175">Template Name</asp:Label>
                </td>
                <td class="MCRSFieldEditCell">
                  <asp:TextBox ID="txtEmailTemplate_TemplateName" CssClass="TextBoxStyle" runat="server"
                    Width="100%"></asp:TextBox>
                </td>
                <td class="MCRSFieldLabelCell">
                  <asp:Label ID="lblEmailTemplate_TemplateType" CssClass="LabelStyle" runat="server"
                    Width="175">Template Type</asp:Label>
                </td>
                <td class="MCRSFieldEditCell">
                  <asp:RadioButtonList ID="rblEmailTemplate_TemplateType" CssClass="RadioButtonListStyle"
                    runat="server" RepeatColumns="1" RepeatDirection="Horizontal" Width="135px">
                    <asp:ListItem Value="1">Cover Letter</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem Value="2">Email</asp:ListItem>
                  </asp:RadioButtonList>
                </td>
                <td class="MCRSRowRightCell">
                  &nbsp;
                </td>
              </tr>
              <tr class="MCRSFieldRow">
                <td class="MCRSFieldLabelCell">
                  Composition Date
                </td>
                <td class="MCRSFieldEditCell">
                  <asp:Label ID="lblEmailTemplate_CompositionDate" CssClass="ElementLabelStyle" runat="server"
                    Width="175"></asp:Label>
                </td>
                <td class="MCRSFieldLabelCell">
                  Last Used Date
                </td>
                <td class="MCRSFieldEditCell">
                  <asp:Label ID="lblEmailTemplate_LastUsedDate" CssClass="ElementLabelStyle" runat="server"
                    Width="175"></asp:Label>
                </td>
                <td class="MCRSRowRightCell">
                  &nbsp;
                </td>
              </tr>
              <tr class="MCRSFieldRow">
                <td class="MCRSFieldLabelCell">
                  Composed By
                </td>
                <td class="MCRSFieldEditCell" colspan="3">
                  <asp:Label ID="lblPerson_FirstNames" CssClass="ElementLabelStyle" runat="server"></asp:Label>
                  <asp:Label ID="lblPerson_LastName" CssClass="ElementLabelStyle" runat="server"></asp:Label>
                </td>
                <td class="MCRSRowRightCell">
                  &nbsp;
                </td>
              </tr>
              <tr class="MCRSFieldRow">
                <td class="MCRSFieldLabelCell">
                  <asp:Label ID="lblEmailTemplate_Subject" CssClass="LabelStyle" runat="server" Width="175">Subject</asp:Label>
                </td>
                <td class="MCRSFieldEditCell" colspan="3">
                  <asp:TextBox ID="txtEmailTemplate_Subject" CssClass="TextBoxStyle" runat="server"
                    Width="100%"></asp:TextBox>
                </td>
                <td class="MCRSRowRightCell">
                  &nbsp;
                </td>
              </tr>
              <tr class="MCRSFieldRow">
                <td class="style1">
                  <asp:Label ID="lblEmailTemplate_Body" CssClass="LabelStyle" runat="server" Width="175">Body</asp:Label>
                </td>
                <td class="style1" colspan="3">
                  <FCKeditorV2:FCKeditor ID="FCKeditor1" runat="server" Height="500px">
                  </FCKeditorV2:FCKeditor>
                </td>
                <td class="style2">
                  &nbsp;
                </td>
              </tr>
            </table>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </div>
    <p>
      <a class="InputButtonStyle" href="#_swTopOfPage">Top of Page</a>
    </p>
  </div>
  <uc1:footer ID="footer1" runat="server" />
  <p>
    <asp:TextBox ID="txtEmailTemplate_Body" CssClass="TextAreaStyle" Rows="4" runat="server"
      Width="100%" Height="16px" Visible="False"></asp:TextBox>
  </p>
  </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 4):

Problem with getting value from FCKeditor (FCKeditor.Value) at ASP.Net
1. If initial value FCKeditor.Value not set, there is no problem, all values, which are placed to FCKeditor can get with FCKeditor.Value.
2. Problem: if initial value FCKeditor.Value is not null, then if I want get value, it gives me only initial value.

I have solved!!!!
I spent the whole day ... Hardly found the answer.
Specially registered to write a reply!
Look! Example:

// Set initial value to FCKeditor

```
void Page_Init(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
DataTable dT_01 = new DataTable();
      dT_01 = DataLayerMainContent.ArticlesSelect(2);
      FCKeditor_Edit.Value = dT_01.Rows[0]["ArticleText"].ToString();
}
```

Attention!!!
You have not to do this here!!

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Not here!!!
}
```

// And get Value from FCKeditor

```
protected void Btn_ContentEditedSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //FCKeditor_Edit.Value
    // And add this value to DataBase
    DataLayerAdminPost.ContentMainEdit(1, FCKeditor_Edit.Value);
    Response.Redirect(Request.RawUrl);
}
```

Main Idea!
Set initial value to FCKeditor at Page_Init!

Comment: Wow, it's nearly 2 years since I had this problem - and I really appreciate you sharing this!  In the meantime, I've long since moved on from that project, so unfortunately I can't even test your answer, much less accept it.  But +1 for the effort!  Hopefully someone else will benefit from your research!

Answer (score 1):

Have you got ViewState enabled? **ANS = Yes**

**EDIT:  OK, then inside the Page_Init event try adding the following:**

```
Page.RegisterRequiresPostBack(FCKeditor1);
```

Answer (score 1):

The solution above didn't work for me, however i found solution [here](http://jlcoady.net/aspnet/fckeditor-work-inside-updatepanel)

Here's code what I used

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ScriptManager.RegisterOnSubmitStatement(
        this, 
        this.GetType(), 
        "AjaxHack", "for ( var i = 0; i < parent.frames.length; ++i ) if ( parent.frames[i].FCK ) parent.frames[i].FCK.UpdateLinkedField();");
}
```

Hope that saves someones day. I was looking for the solution for 2 months.

Cheers